# Ошибка: IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, telebot, sqlite3

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['energydrink', 'энергетик'], chat_type=[types.ChatType.SUPERGROUP, types.ChatType.GROUP])
async def drinkenergy(message: types.Message):
        tmpconnect = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
        tmpcursor = tmpconnect.cursor()

    number = random.uniform(1, 5)
    number = float('{:.1f}'.format(number))

    tmpcursor.execute("UPDATE users SET number = number + ? WHERE user_id = ?", (number, user_id))

    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'@{message.from_user.username}, ты выпил(а) {number} л. энергетика.', reply_markup=deletemarkup)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**db.py**

```
import sqlite3
import time

class Database:
    def __init__(self, db_file):
        self.connection = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()

    def user_exists(self, user_id):
        with self.connection:
            result = self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = ?", (user_id,)).fetchall()
            return bool(len(result))
            
    def add_user(self, user_id):
        with self.connection:
            return self.connection.execute("INSERT INTO `users` (`user_id`) VALUES (?)", (user_id,))
```

Comment: что у вас с отступами?

Comment: @oleksandrigo в каком смысле? Я может не правильно понял..
Вроде-бы нормально с отступами у меня.

Comment: неа, и ошибка вам об этом и говорит. Вы когда-то пытались переводить текст ошибок? Думаю стоит начать. А вообще вопрос, зачем у вас две табуляции перед `tmpconnect`?

Comment: @Riktik, при написании кода в качестве отступов используй либо табуляцию, либо пробелы. Желательно второе.

Comment: @oleksandrigo обновил вопрос, добавил db.py. А вот у меня есть файл bd.py. Я пробовал на прямую, но как-то можно сделать чтобы переменная "number" просто передавалась как-то? и там уже в db.py, к числу которое стоит будет + number.

Comment: зачем мне ваша БД? У вас была конкретная проблема с отступами, она вроде как решена - вопрос закрыт.

Comment: Да и вообще вы же умеете делать селект? По айди юзера возьмите столбец с числом, добавьте к нему что вы там хотите и сделайте апдейт в бд.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['energydrink', 'энергетик'], chat_type=[types.ChatType.SUPERGROUP, types.ChatType.GROUP])
async def drinkenergy(message: types.Message):
    tmpconnect = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
    tmpcursor = tmpconnect.cursor()

    number = random.uniform(1, 5)
    number = float('{:.1f}'.format(number))

    tmpcursor.execute("UPDATE users SET number = number + ? WHERE user_id = ?", (number, user_id))

    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'@{message.from_user.username}, ты выпил(а) {number} л. энергетика.', reply_markup=deletemarkup)
```